# Does Cyanogenmod 13 support APT-X (on my Moto G)

Tags: cyanogenmod

just a short question. Does CM13 have APT-X support built in? For my moto g, it has from stock (as it's website reads), and now I'm wondering if Cyanogenmod has it too, because its proprietary and has to be built into the bluetooth stack afaik (so, no ordinary codec).

Thanks :)